# What kind of genetic problems would arise after three, five and ten generations of inbreeding?

Tags: humans, genetics, history, ancient-history, family

In this case I'm assuming that the family has been inbreeding to a [level of 2](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Table_of_Consanguinity_showing_degrees_of_relationship.svg/800px-Table_of_Consanguinity_showing_degrees_of_relationship.svg.png) or closer for a certain amount of generations. Given this what would be the likely issues that would arise after:

1. Two Generations
2. Three Generations
3. Five Generations
4. Ten Generations

I'm curious to know what kind of effects this would have. Also how would relations be between family members other than the obvious? I'm trying to build this in a world that is currently in its Iron Age.

Comment: You've read about [Charles II of Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_II_of_Spain), right?

Comment: Downvotes without comments are unhelpful, folks, especially for new users.

Comment: Curious to hear from the closer about why he believes this is opinion based, the common genetic problems are fairly well documented & studied within reproductive biology & medical science so not a lot of wriggle room for 'opinion' in a reasonable answer I'd have thought.

Comment: Insufficient information.  It all depends on the stock you started with.

Comment: What genetic problems did [Cleopatra VII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra), the famous queen of Egypt, have? She was a very attractive, very intelligent and very active woman, and she was the last sovereign of the [Ptolemaic dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemaic_dynasty), which had practiced inbreeding for some three centuries. Your inbred dynasty may have no genetic problems, or it may have a propensity for, I don't know, catching colds easily. Depends on what story you want to tell: and this is what "primarily opinion based" means.

Comment: this is entirely dependent on what genes the starting population has.

Comment: @AlexP *"She was a very attractive, very intelligent and very active woman"* we only have her word & Anthony's for that & neither of them are likely to have told us otherwise if she wasn't are they, would have reflected badly on him (dating her & all) to admit otherwise wouldn't it :))

Comment: @Pelinore: Antony's (no aitch is better, the name is not Greek) *and Caesar's*. She seduced  *both* of them... (Perhaps unitentionally, but through her actions she made Egypt part of the Roman world for some two decades. This gradual approach led to a "natural" incorporation of Egypt in the empire as one of the most important provinces; it remained a Roman province for six centuries.)

Comment: @AlexP that she managed to snag multiple powerful men does suggest she may really have been attractive doesn't it :) on the other hand lets not forget that power itself (which she had in spades) has a glamour all its own (even to those that already have a lot of power of their own) which could also explain her conquests, I've never been convinced either way on the subject of her beauty, seen far too many modern & semi modern ugly royals described as beautiful for that :))

Answer (score 1):

it would vary how long it could take to see large effects. the major factor would be how far down the family tree is the nearest common ancestor of the two parents. the major effects stay the same, but just get more pronounced over time. These are typically reduced fertility rates and an increase in the likelihood of having genetic diseases.